# How to retrieve a pdf/image from reference field using MongoEngine?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, flask-restful, flask-mongoengine

I finding some difficulty in retrieving a pdf/image file that is referenced by a class using flask from mongodb. For example, I have this model:

```
class Users(db.Document):
    _id = db.StringField()
    name = db.StringField()
    picture = db.ReferenceField('fs.files')
    email = db.StringField()
    password = db.StringField()
    meta = {'collection': 'Users'}
```

The JSON for a record in the Users table would look like this:

```
{
    "_id": "1", 
    "name": "John Doe", 
    "picture": {
        "$ref": "fs.files", 
        "$id": {
            "$oid": "5e1...a932"
         }
     }, 
     "email":"john.doe@example.come", 
     "password": "12345"
}
```

Using this model in a Flask Restful api, I'm trying to retrieve the image associated with the user to display in my application. Also, when a new user is added, how do I save the file with the reference in the User table? The reference for the image is stored in the picture field. I also want to do this for pdfs in the same manner.

I've tried looking at GridFS but I'm not quite understanding how it works or how to implement it in my flask api with mongoengine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `send_file` extension from Flask to create an url that loads the static file as response.

```
from flask import send_file

@app.route('/get-image/<user>')
def get-image(user):
    """Serves static image loaded from db."""

    user = Users.objects(name=user).first()

    return send_file(io.BytesIO(user.picture.read()),
                     attachment_filename='image.jpg',
                     mimetype='image/jpg')
```

In order to the above solution get to work, you should use `FileField()` instead of `ReferenceField()` on your document model:

PS: I'm not sure if you can archieve this using the ReferenceField, the method below uses gridfs, which seems to be the appropriate way.

```
class Users(db.Document):
    _id = db.StringField()
    name = db.StringField()
    picture = db.FileField()
    email = db.StringField()
    password = db.StringField()
    meta = {'collection': 'Users'}
```

And you can load the file into the model like this:

```
user = Users.objects(name='User123').first()

with open('pic.jpg', 'rb') as fd:
    user.picture.put(fd, content_type = 'image/jpeg')
user.save()
```

Hope it suits you nicely

http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/gridfs.html

Comment: Thanks much! I'll try this out and let you know how it goes!